# How to avoid community licences cost for public user in salesforce

Tags: community, userlicense

I've to create a website, where public user can able to register/login on website and make a business with company.

The above requirement is developed by using community in salesforce. 
now when the public user register on website, it create a user in salesforce and occupied a licences.

same way multiple public user ware registering on website and by creating the user it occupying licences.

Now the problem is, so many people registering on website but all of them not doing business for now or not know when they will. but we need to pay user licence fee per month to salesforce.

So how can we avoid this, or any other way.

Comment: If the users need to register you will need licences, the alternative to the per user licence model for communities is the login based licences where you pay for a number of logins per month rather than per user.

Comment: You do not want to avoid this, it would bypass the agreement you have made with salesforce if they are accessing a salesforce community. Don't do it on salesforce if you are not willing to pay for the value you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is assuming that you are using Customer Community Licences, it will be different if you use Partner Community licences.

The Customer Community Login licence type may be more appropriate for your use case as any user that can login to the community will need a licence, but if you have large numbers of registered users that will not make much use of the community it gives a lower cost.

With Login based licences the cost will be based on the number of logins per month not the number of users as the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0) describes.

> When using a monthly login-based license, a user consumes a login when signing in to a community. Already logged-in users don’t consume licenses when switching between their communities. Overages are calculated at the end of the year rather than on a monthly basis. There’s a 1 to 20 login to user ratio limit. For example, if you purchased 1000 monthly logins, you can create up to 20,000 users.

As always with licencing issues it is important to discuss this with your Salesforce Account Executive as they will have the current pricing information and know if any kind of deal can be done for your company.

Comment: If I've to use user login based licneces, then for  community user I've to give which licences? Customer Community Login  or Customer Community licence.

Comment: Customer Community Login

Comment: Thanks for your great help. one question please.  If I've a 100 Customer Community Login licences. so Can i apply "Customer Community Login" licence for 200 community user.

Comment: Sorry didn't quite understand your last comment. If you had Customer Community Login with 100 logins per month it would allow 2,000 Community users to be created.